# Text goes out the margins in paracol

Tags: margins, columns, paracol

I have an issue with the package paracol. I am using it for the Acknowledgements of my Master Thesis. I am writing them in two languages. The problem is that some words go out the margin. This does not happen with \lipsum, that is why I have pasted the actual text.

```
\setlength{\columnsep}{24pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\normalsize

\begin{paracol}{2}

First and foremost I will start with my supervisor, Alessandro. This Thesis is my most important educational achievement so far and I want to dedicate it to him. He has been a marvellous surprise, a positive exception to the rule, the most beautiful one. That is why just a "thanks" to him is definitely not enough. He has literally breathed this Thesis together with me. He supported me throughout my work with his patience and knowledge whilst allowing me the room to work in my own way. I had the possibility to grow in a remarkably professional environment and I attribute this achievement to his encouragement and effort. Being a student means having a significant gap between me and the people I was surrounded with in the department. Alessandro made me always feel like a team member, a colleague. Without him this thesis, too, would not have been completed. One simply could not wish for a better or more friendly supervisor. Without any overstatement, he behaved not just as a supervisor but I see him as a role model, always ready to share his outstanding combination of resources, experience and abilities.

\switchcolumn

Il primo ringraziamento va al mio supervisore, Alessandro. Questa Tesi \`e la mia pi\`u importante conquista accademica e voglio dedicarla a lui. Ecco perch\`e un semplice "grazie" \`e definitivamente non sufficiente. \`E stato una bellissima sorpresa, un'eccezione positiva alla regola, la pi\`u bella. Ha letteralmente respirato questa Tesi insieme a me. Mi ha supportato attraverso il mio lavoro con la sua pazienza e conoscenza, allo stesso tempo dandomi libert\`a di lavorare secondo i miei canoni. Ho avuto la possibilit\`a di lavorare in un ambiente significativamente professionale e attribuisco questo risultato al suo incoraggiamento e sforzo. Essere uno studente significa avere un gap tra me e le persone da cui ero circondato nel dipartimento. Alessandro mi ha dato l'opportunit\`a di sentirmi parte di una squadra, un collega. Senza di lui anche questa Tesi non sarebbe stata completata. Semplicemente non si potrebbe desiderare di avere un miglior e cos\`i amichevole supervisore. Senza esagerazioni, \`e stato per me non solo un supervisore, ma un modello da seguire, sempre pronto a condividere la sua notevole combinazione di risorse, esperienza e abilit\`a.

\end{paracol}
```

Answer (score 7):

`\sloppy` or, as shown below, the `sloppypar` environment, fixes the problem. See, for example, [How to relax the horizontal spacing rules for one line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199382/how-to-relax-the-horizontal-spacing-rules-for-one-line/199383#199383).  A multi-column document places added constraints on satisfying column alignments, whcih can be difficult for TeX to satisfy.  Another option would be `{\raggedright\begin{paracol}{2}...\end{paracol}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\columnsep}{24pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\normalsize
\begin{sloppypar}
\begin{paracol}{2}

First and foremost I will start with my supervisor, Alessandro. This Thesis is my most important educational achievement so far and I want to dedicate it to him. He has been a marvellous surprise, a positive exception to the rule, the most beautiful one. That is why just a "thanks" to him is definitely not enough. He has literally breathed this Thesis together with me. He supported me throughout my work with his patience and knowledge whilst allowing me the room to work in my own way. I had the possibility to grow in a remarkably professional environment and I attribute this achievement to his encouragement and effort. Being a student means having a significant gap between me and the people I was surrounded with in the department. Alessandro made me always feel like a team member, a colleague. Without him this thesis, too, would not have been completed. One simply could not wish for a better or more friendly supervisor. Without any overstatement, he behaved not just as a supervisor but I see him as a role model, always ready to share his outstanding combination of resources, experience and abilities.

\switchcolumn

Il primo ringraziamento va al mio supervisore, Alessandro. Questa Tesi \`e la mia pi\`u importante conquista accademica e voglio dedicarla a lui. Ecco perch\`e un semplice "grazie" \`e definitivamente non sufficiente. \`E stato una bellissima sorpresa, un'eccezione positiva alla regola, la pi\`u bella. Ha letteralmente respirato questa Tesi insieme a me. Mi ha supportato attraverso il mio lavoro con la sua pazienza e conoscenza, allo stesso tempo dandomi libert\`a di lavorare secondo i miei canoni. Ho avuto la possibilit\`a di lavorare in un ambiente significativamente professionale e attribuisco questo risultato al suo incoraggiamento e sforzo. Essere uno studente significa avere un gap tra me e le persone da cui ero circondato nel dipartimento. Alessandro mi ha dato l'opportunit\`a di sentirmi parte di una squadra, un collega. Senza di lui anche questa Tesi non sarebbe stata completata. Semplicemente non si potrebbe desiderare di avere un miglior e cos\`i amichevole supervisore. Senza esagerazioni, \`e stato per me non solo un supervisore, ma un modello da seguire, sempre pronto a condividere la sua notevole combinazione di risorse, esperienza e abilit\`a.

\end{paracol}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

[image]