# Paracol alignment and justification

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, expex, paracol

I am using `paracol` together with `expex` and am having two problems:

1. Vertical alignment between the two columns (Issue #1 in red). I would like the tops (red lines) of each opposing paragraph to align consistently throughout the document, which will be much longer than this one page example.
2. Horizontal alignment in the skinny column. Some of the words overflow (Issue #2 in blue), and I want that to *never* happen. With `parbox`es it never happens, but I would like to avoid `parbox` in this case. How to ensure a tightly packed column within `paracol`?

I [previously](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357317/problems-aligning-left-and-right-columns-in-paracol) posted a similar question around Issue #1, but the solution does not work for this case.

**MWE (compile in XeTeX):**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=8in,
    paperheight=10in,
    inner=0.6in,
    outer=0.6in,
    bindingoffset=0.15in,
    top=0.6in,
    bottom=0.6in,
    twoside]{geometry}  
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{paracol}
    \twosided[pc]
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{FrankRuehl}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}

\hyphenpenalty 200 %helps to force justification of skinny column
\tolerance 2000 %helps to force justification of skinny column

\lingset{
    everygla=\Large, 
    everyglb=\scriptsize\englishfont\it,
    everyglc=\scriptsize\englishfont,
    glwordalign=center,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt,
    glhangstyle=none,
    %glspace=0.5em plus 3em minus 0.15em,   
    aboveglbskip=-0.7ex,%adjust space between gla & glb
    aboveglcskip=-0.7ex %adjust space between glb & glc
}

\columnratio{0.75}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em}

\newenvironment{interlinear}%
    {\begin{leftcolumn*}\begin{hebrew}\exdisplay\begingl}%
    {\endgl\xe\end{hebrew}\end{leftcolumn*}}
\newenvironment{translation}%
    {\begin{rightcolumn}\small\noindent\ignorespaces}%
    {\end{rightcolumn}}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{interlinear}
\gla אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו //

  \glb Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.  //

  \glc Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.  //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. 
\end{translation}

\begin{interlinear}
\gla אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו //

  \glb Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.  //

  \glc Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.  //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. 
\end{translation}

\begin{interlinear}
\gla אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו //

  \glb Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.  //

  \glc Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.  //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. 
\end{translation}

\begin{interlinear}
\gla אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו זזז חחח טטטטטטטטט ייייי ככככככ לללללל אאא בבבבב גגגגגג דדדדדד ההההה ווווו //

  \glb Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.  //

  \glc Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.  //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. 
\end{translation}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answers are to add a custom `strut` and also `sloppy` in `\newenvironment{translation}`.

```
\newenvironment{interlinear}%
    {\begin{leftcolumn*}\begin{hebrew}\exdisplay\begingl}%
    {\endgl\xe\end{hebrew}\end{leftcolumn*}}
\newenvironment{translation}%
    {\begin{rightcolumn}\small\noindent\ignorespaces\mystrut\sloppy}
    {\end{rightcolumn}}

\newcommand{\mystrut}{\rule{-3pt}{33pt}}
```

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357332/121944) and also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200162/121944) were helpful in solving these problems.

The `strut` part of the solution isn't perfect though. I sometimes still have side-by-side paragraph alignment issues over a page break.

**I could still use a better solution.**