# Line wrapping with underscores

Tags: pdftex, hyperref

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20892). There, a method is described how to "escape underscores". I would like to use that to put hyperlinks into the margin.

[image: link text overflows to the right]

As you can see, with a very long link text, this overflows and doesn't break.

I would like it to break without inserting dashes. I tried `\linebreak` but that messes up the link URL.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}


% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20892>
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\escapeus}[1]{%
  \begingroup\@activeus\scantokens{#1\endinput}\endgroup}
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_\relax
   \lowercase{\endgroup\def\@activeus{\catcode`\_=\active \let~\_}}

\newcommand\thyrefdist[1]{\marginpar{\href{https://some.web.site/#1.html}{\texttt{\escapeus{#1}}}}}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

Test\thyrefdist{Very_Long_Text_That_Does_Not_Wrap}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}




\newcommand\thyrefdist[1]{\marginpar{\href{https://#1.html}{\path{#1}}}}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

Test\thyrefdist{Very_Long_Text_That_Does_Not_Wrap}

\end{document}
```

Comment: if it wasn't for hiding the `https` and `.html`  you could have had simply `\marginpar{\url{#1}}`

Answer (score 1):

In an embarassing turn of events, I managed to figure it out. [Another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9938/172786) describes how to redefine `\_` such that it also allows breaks. The key appears to be to only do that redefinition scoped to the escaping macro.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\escapeus}[1]{%
  \begingroup\renewcommand\_{\textunderscore\allowbreak}\@activeus\scantokens{#1\endinput}\endgroup}
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_\relax
   \lowercase{\endgroup\def\@activeus{\catcode`\_=\active \let~\_}}
```